# Using the urls from parsed info from a JSON file to display the images in the URLs

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, android-volley

Im using a GET Request with Volley:

**HTTPRequest.java**

```
public void get(String url) {

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            getReponse(), createMyReqErrorListener()) {

        @Override
        protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "deliverResponse= " + response.toString());
            super.deliverResponse(response);
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put(ACCEPT, ACCEPT_JSON);
            headers.put(AUTH_ID, AUTH_ID_VALUE);
            headers.put(PLATFORM, PLATFORM_VALUE);
            headers.put(CID, "");
            System.out.println(headers.toString());
            return headers;
        }
    };

    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(request);
}
```

to grab a JSON from a url below is an example of the JSON (Dummy content):

**JSON File on remote server**

```
{
 "Errors": null,
 "Session": {
 "SessionId": ""
},
 "someUrl": "http://www.someurl.com",
 "BlockPromotions": {
 "@CategoryId": "1",
 "Type": "PAGE",
 "Items": {
  "Item": [
    {
      "@Id": "2",
      "DisplayImage": "http://imageurl/something.png",
      "DisplayOrder": "1"
    },
    {
      "@Id": "3",
      "DisplayImage": "http://imageurl/something_else.png",
      "DisplayOrder": "2"
    }
  ]
}
}
}
```

The code I am using to parse the JSON is below:

**Parser.java**

```
public String parseResponse(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        JSONObject objectBlockPromo = response.getJSONObject("BlockPromotions");
        JSONObject objectItems = objectBlockPromo.getJSONObject("Items");
        JSONArray arrayItem = objectItems.getJSONArray("Item");
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayItem.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject item = arrayItem.getJSONObject(i);
            ImageURL = item.getString("DisplayImage");
            System.out.println(ImageURL);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ImageURL;
}
```

I managed to grab all the url's individually, my problem is handing those URL's back over to the HomeScreen, to display the images?

How would I do this?

I have tried using the URL as a String, I have also tried (but I think I did it incorrectly) using ImageRequest from Volley to grab the URL.

Thanks

Comment: I feel like the title of your question is misleading. You are able to retrieve and retrieve and use the data from the json document. Now you want to display images for which you know the URL.

Comment: good point i will change it! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to open a connection to the URL, download the image and then display it.

```
                String name = "yourdesiredfilename";
                URL url = new URL(src);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                OutputStream output = openFileOutput(name, MODE_PRIVATE);
                IOUtils.copy(input, output);
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(input);
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(output);
```

(IOUtils just because I am lazy ;))
Then you have the file locally and can pass it to an ImageView or whatever you have.

```
                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(pathName);
                ImageView yourView;
                yourView.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Comment: Im already using Volley to pull down the JSON. In my mind i was thinking i could use the URL provided in the JSON to maybe be downloaded with ImageRequest from Volley? Im sure there is a better way than having to do 2 requests like that?

Comment: Well at some point you have to download the image and show it from a local copy. Whether you do this via url connection, a library like glide or Volley is personal taste.

Answer (score 0):

In some point you are going to need cache the photos that you download, so what I recommend is try to use some of the most commonly used ImageLoader libraries.

Most popular, recommended by Google: [Picasso](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en) or [Glide](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en).

After importing some of those utils into your project, in some point you just have to call a function like mImageLoader(mPhotoUrl) and attach it to your ImageView or whatever, and finally reach the goal of your question ;-).

I know it's not a very specific answer but I would have desired that someone told me this when I was struggling with the same things.